# VBA Multi-step error when SQL Select includes nvarchar column with length greater than 100

Tags: excel, sql-server-ce, vba

I've written an Excel VB application that accesses and, when needed, modifies an SQLCE database.  Here's the connection string in vba:

```
dbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=C:\sitsDB.sdf;"
```

I'm almost completely done with the project and everything works great except I want to expand one of the fields in the SQLCE database file to allow for more characters to be store.
This field is of data type `nvarchar` and the default length is 100 (which apparently should allow 50 characters?)

The field is needed for an open text box that I would at least like to store 200 characters in.

I created the initial database in Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express, when I change the length of the `nvarchar` field to anything greater than 100 I get the following error when my `SQL SELECT` statement runs:

> Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)':
>       Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status Value.

Here is the SQL statement in VBA:

```
With rsResults
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM Incidents WHERE Number = " & number
    Set .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .Open
End With
```

The error occurs on the `.Open` line.

I can change the `SELECT * FROM` to select only certain columns eliminating the field that has a length greater than 100 and everything will work as expected.

So, it is definitely the fact that one field has a length greater than 100. 
If I return that field to having a length of 100 everything will work OK as well...

I don't know much about the `.CursorLocation` and `.CursorType` functions that I'm using there.  I learned by example and that's the example I found first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In writing this explanation out I realized that I hadn't tried some things.  Namely, I hadn't fooled around with the `.CursorLocation` and `.CursorType`.  It turns out that changing `.CursorLocation` to `.CursorLocation = adUseServer` will fix the problem I was seeing.  I can now use length of nvarchar all the way up to 4000.